# how to conclude a subset of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is compact from spectral radius?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, lie-groups

could any one tell me which of the following is/are compact subset?

1. $S=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{C}): \rho (A)\le 1\}$
2. $S=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{C}): A=A^*,\rho (A)\le 1\}$
3. $S=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{C}): AA^*=A^*A=I\}$

I  pointed out that only $2$ is compact by the map $Ap:\mapsto A-A^*$ gives $S=p^{-1}(O)$ hence closed and clearly this set is bounded.

$3$ is just $O_n(\mathbb{C})$ I can prove that it is not bounded so not compact

Comment: It seems $A^*$ is the Hermitian adjoint, so 3. is $U(n)$, compact. And $2$ is the image of the map from $U(n)\times D$ to $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, $(u,d) \mapsto u d u^{-1}$ ($d$ diagonal matrix), so compact if the spectrum is bounded and closed.

Comment: $S$ in (1) is not bounded. Consider, e.g., matrices in the form $A=\pmatrix{1&\alpha\\0&1}$. The spectrum is nicely bounded by $1$, but any norm of $A$ can be made arbitrarily large.

Comment: @orangeskid does that mean correct option is 2 and 3

Comment: to all dudes, what is the general set up to tackle this kind of questions?

Comment: @learnmore: Yes, 2 and 3.  2 is also convex. 1 is not convex.

Comment: @El Angel Exterminador: For hermitian matrices, the spectrum only will determine compactness, closedness, and sometime convexity. For general matrices, one should be careful, as Algebraic Pavel pointed out.

Comment: thanks for your answer @orangeskid